# How to search an embedded Google Spreadsheet in Google Sites?

Tags: google-sheets, google-search, google-classic-sites

I would like to know how I can make embedded spreadsheets searchable in Google Sites.

Answer (score 1):

I've prepared this answer to publish a spreadsheet: [publish spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36765/is-is-possible-to-have-part-of-a-google-doc-hidden-publicly-but-able-to-be-edite/37095#37095).
Follow the link to my homepage and you will end-up at the embedded sheet.

This sheet isn't searchable via the build-in search function of Google Sites, but via <kbd>Crtl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> it is searchable.