# Is is possible to have part of a google doc hidden publicly but able to be edited and "pushed" to LIVE?

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a public schedule for my business, but need to edit (which sometimes takes a few days) and then make "public"...
Can I do that?

I know I can "hide" but when I reopen, it's live and everyone can access it...another way to handle?

Answer (score 3):

After having done some research and having asked the right questions, I can present you this solution:

1. Use a master sheet to prepare your data.
   I've created another one: Mastersheet - ARRAYFORMULA
   But here's the catch: if your interested in this answer, send me an e-mail (see my [profile](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/29140/jacob-jan-tuinstra)) and I will add you to the privately shared file.
2. Create another sheet to hold the public data.
   Use the `ARRAYFORMULA` to retrieve only the first two columns.
3. Publish the public sheet:
   [image]
4. Select the sheet named Public:
   [image]
5. Select the URL to publish:
   [image]
6. You can send out the [URL](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdDlTRFZGRk1UZ09vRjh4TDBqTU00TlE&single=true&gid=2&output=html) or display it on a [website](https://sites.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/main/masterpubli)

For the sake of transparency, I've not deleted my previous answer.

Comment: An alternative to the use of `ARRAYFORMULA` is the use of arrays in the new Google Sheets (instead of `=ARRAYFORMULA(A:B)` use `={A:B}`). See [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way, but it's not an elegant one:

1. Use a master sheet to prepare your data, publicly shared.
   I've created a file myself: [master sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdEhCelpkM1NzR0thdURmaXdoREpuZ3c)
2. Create a public sheet and use the [IMPORTRANGE](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=155183) formula.
   See example file I created: [public sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdDRxNnFsUnNSYkRFWE51bk9kYU1La1E)
3. Use Google Sites to display the public sheet via an iFrame:
   Use the [iFrame Wrapper](https://sites.google.com/site/mori79/html-gadgets/how-tos/embed-docs) created by [Mori](https://sites.google.com/site/mori79/home/about-me).
   See example website page I created: [Google Sites Page](https://sites.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/main/masterpubli)

This way the key of the master sheet is not traceable.

Follow this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/36842/29140) I've asked about finding public documents.