# How to protect documents, spreadsheets, presentations which are shared on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I shared some documents, spreadsheets, presentations on Google Drive but I want to restrict users from downloading or copying them.

I want users be able only to view these files, not edit, copy or download them.

How I can do this?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37380/how-to-lock-a-google-document

Answer (score 1):

You could use "Publish to the Web" (File > Publish to the web). It generates a page with the documents content and cryptic link. Visitors can only view the content. Here is an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AvxYoiW50CjLdC1QRDh5eEQyRWZ4NGJmZVEydTk5X2c&output=html

Maybe that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You do this through the File | Share... menu option in the document viewer. However, there are some restrictions.

Don't share it with the public.  Just share it with specific users under File | Share.

Anyone you give read access to the file can Download or Copy it.  I don't believe Google provides a way to share a file without the user being able to Download and Copy it. They can't edit or add to your published copy of the file, but they can subsequently modify their own copy and re-publish it on their own account.

Anyone you give edit permission to, can obviously edit your copy of the document, so if this is not intended, don't give edit permission...

For more information on visibility options, check this Google support doc:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494886?rd=1

Answer (score -1):

It’s very easy: just right-click on your doc and click *Share* and then choose *View only* or any other option according to your needs.